# Can't Delete Column, Error When Trying to Create New Column

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to drop a few columns that I don't need from Parse. I keep getting the following error:

> Error: classname '_Session' must start with a letter parse

Not sure why this is happening - or if this is a bug. Same issue when I add a new column in a class from parse, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that is affecting a lot of users. The official bug thread for the issue can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1539329073009016/

Comment: Yup. Parse bug, wait it out.